# ImageCollection (Error) ImageCollection.fromImages, argument 'images': Invalid type

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api, mean

I want to extract ET for Odisha region excluding waterbody and build up area. For that I calculate MNDWI and NDBI and create mask. But when I am applying it for extracting monthly ET the error is coming:

> ImageCollection (Error)ImageCollection.fromImages, argument 'images':
> Invalid type.Expected type: List<Image>. Actual type:
> List<Dictionary>.Actual value: [{year=2016,
> ET=83.79211964326004}, {year=2016,
> Actually I have no idea to extract time series by masking.

```
/**** Start of imports. If edited, may not auto-convert in the playground. ****/
var roi = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-tbhattacharya/assets/odisha");
/***** End of imports. If edited, may not auto-convert in the playground. *****/

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2').filterDate('2016-12-31', '2017-04-30').filterBounds(roi).sort('CLOUD_COVER');
print(collection);
var outline = ee.Image().byte().paint({
  featureCollection: roi,
  color: 1,
  width: 3
});
Map.addLayer(outline, {pallette: ['black']},"Study Area");
Map.centerObject(roi, 8);
function addNDBI(image){
  var ndbi = image.expression(
    "((SWIR-NIR)/(SWIR+NIR))",{
      'NIR'    : image.select('SR_B5'),
      'SWIR'    : image.select('SR_B6')
    }).rename('ndbi');
    return image.addBands(ndbi);
}
var LC09ndbi = collection.map (addNDBI);
var LC09ndbi = LC09ndbi.select('ndbi').median();
var clipndbi = LC09ndbi.clip(roi);
Export.image.toDrive({
  image : clipndbi,
  folder : 'Landsat 09',
  description : 'NDBI_L9',
  crs : 'EPSG:4326',
  region : roi,
  scale :30,
  maxPixels: 3784216672400,
  fileFormat : 'GEOTIFF',
  formatOptions : {
    cloudOptimized :true
    
  }
  
  
})
/***** End of imports. If edited, may not auto-convert in the playground. *****/
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA').filterDate('2016-12-31', '2017-04-30').filterBounds(roi).sort('CLOUD_COVER');
print(collection);
var outline = ee.Image().byte().paint({
  featureCollection: roi,
  color: 1,
  width: 3
});
Map.addLayer(outline, {pallette: ['black']},"Study Area");
Map.centerObject(roi, 8);
function addMNDWI(image){
  var mndwi = image.expression(
    "((Green-SWIR)/(Green+SWIR))",{
      'Green'    : image.select('B3'),
      'SWIR'    : image.select('B6')
    }).rename('mndwi');
    return image.addBands(mndwi);
}
var LC09mndwi = collection.map (addMNDWI);
var LC09mndwi = LC09mndwi.select('mndwi').median();
var clipmndwi = LC09mndwi.clip(roi);
Export.image.toDrive({
  image : clipmndwi,
  folder : 'Landsat 09',
  description : 'MNDWI_L9',
  crs : 'EPSG:4326',
  region : roi,
  scale :30,
  maxPixels: 3784216672400,
  fileFormat : 'GEOTIFF',
  formatOptions : {
    cloudOptimized :true
    
  }
  
  
})
var threshold = clipndbi.gt(0.1);
var threshold1= clipmndwi.gt(0.055)
var mask1 = threshold.updateMask(threshold);
var mask2 = threshold.updateMask(threshold1);
var mask3 = mask1.blend(mask2)

var ET = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD16A2").filterBounds(roi).filterDate('2016-01-01', '2019-12-31');

var s2_masked = ET.map (function(image){
  // Here comes the same code as for a single Image, 
  // but only replacing the specific variable `test_image` from before with the
  // general parameter `image` that we just specified as the parameter of
  // this function
 return image.updateMask(mask3.unmask().not());
})
print(ET)
//var ET1 = collection.map (ET);
//var ET2 = ET1.updateMask(mask3.unmask().not());

Map.addLayer(ET, {}, 'Output Image');
//var ET2 = ET1.updateMask(mask3.unmask().not());
//Map.addLayer(ET2, {}, 'Output Image')
//var ET1 = mask3.not();
//var output = ET2.mask(ET1);
//Map.addLayer(output, {}, 'Output Image')

var months = ee.List.sequence(1,12)
var years = ee.List([2016,2017,2018,2019])
var ET1 = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function(y){
    return months.map(function(m){
      var w = s2_masked.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year')).filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month')).select('ET').mean().reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), roi , 500)
      return w.set('year', y)
       return w.set('month', m)
       .set(ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1));
    
    });
  }).flatten()
  );
  print(ET1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem code:

```js
var ET1 = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function(y){
    return months.map(function(m){
      var w = s2_masked.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year')).filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month')).select('ET').mean().reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), roi , 500)
      return w.set('year', y)
       return w.set('month', m)
       .set(ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1));
    
    });
  }).flatten()
  );
```

The main issue is that `ee.ImageCollection.fromImages` expects a list of images, but the function you're mapping over `years` is returning a list of dictionaries. Hence the error: `Expected type: List<Image>. Actual type: List<Dictionary>`.

If you want to export monthly statistics of ET, then 1) the mapped function needs to return a list of features instead of dictionaries, and 2) you need to cast it to a `FeatureCollection` instead of an `ImageCollection`.

#### Returning Features from the Mapped Function

In the mapped function, `w` is an `ee.Dictionary` because it was created by `reduceRegion`. You can't export dictionaries directly, so instead you'll need to store the dictionary as the properties of a feature. You can create a feature from it with `ee.Feature(null, w)`.

Another error was that the dictionary was returned immediately after setting the year, so setting the month and date had no effect. Make sure to set all the properties you need and only return once within each function.

#### Storing the Result in a Feature Collection

This is easier. Just replace `ee.ImageCollection.fromImages` with `ee.FeatureCollection`.

Here's the corrected code:

```js
// Store ET1 as a FeatureCollection instead of an ImageCollection
var ET1 = ee.FeatureCollection(
  years.map(function(y){
    return months.map(function(m){
      var w = s2_masked.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year')).filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month')).select('ET').mean().reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), roi , 500)
       // Convert the dictioanry `w` to a Feature (no geometry), set all geometries, and return it
      return ee.Feature(null, w)
        .set('month', m)
        .set('year', y)
        .set('date', ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1));
    });
  }).flatten()
);
```

When you print `ET1`, you'll see it's a feature collection with 48 features. Each feature will have the month, year, date, and ET. You can export that to a CSV with `Export.table.toDrive`.

Comment: Sir the problem is when I masking the result is same as result for no masking. If I have to do some change in my code.

Comment: I have applied masking by var s2_masked = ET.map (function(image){
  // Here comes the same code as for a single Image, 
  // but only replacing the specific variable `test_image` from before with the
  // general parameter `image` that we just specified as the parameter of
  // this function
 return image.updateMask(mask3.unmask().not());
})

Comment: Try `image.updateMask(mask3.mask().not())`. Using `unmask()` disables the mask, which is why it's having no effect.

Comment: Sir, I have applied image.updateMask(mask3.mask().not()) but no change is coming. if there is any error in code